# How to connect to DB on SERVER for Asp.Net membership?

Tags: database, asp.net-membership, connection-string

I've just upload my ASPNETDB.mdf using "Generate Scripts" into server.
The problem is, I don't know how can I connect to it for my Membership.(e.g LogIn Controls)
where is the ConnectionString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update the Data Source tag in web config

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=<<PATH Goes Here>>;Persist Security Info=False;
```

Answer (score 0):

The connectionstring is in the web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the web.config file for your application to redefine the LocalSqlServer connection string to point to the database.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
  <add name="LocalSqlServer"
       connectionString="server=.;database=aspnetdb;
       integrated security=sspi;"/>   
</connectionStrings>
```

If your Membership provider is not pointing to "LocalSqlServer", then you can modify that in the web.config as well.

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, ..."
      connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
      applicationName="/"
      requiresUniqueEmail="false"
      passwordFormat="Hashed"
      maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
      minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
      passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
    />
  </providers>
</membership>
```